# How do you access static file with another static file in django?

Tags: django

I have an html file served as a static file on my site so that I can load it into a rendered page with ajax, in this static html file, I am trying to put images in it but it won't load them on the page.  My directory structure for static files is the base static directory, and then a subfolder for html files, another for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply refer to them relatively from your HTML file.

For example, say you have a file `/static/example.html` and you need to refer to `/static/images/cat.jpg`

You can simply use the relative path images/cat.jpg

Your `<img>` tag would look something like this:
`<img src="images/cat.jpg">`